# Documents downloading in notepad

Tags: windows-10

How do I take off the auto option that has apparently been selected to download files directly to the Notepad instead of to my Open office section?

Comment: is this every website or a particular one?  does this also happen with with local files? or using different browsers?  or ultimately just open c:\whatever\file.doc and see how the browser happens to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming everything else is fine.

Goto...
   Settings/Apps/Default Apps/[Choose default apps by protocol].

You should see a list of items like MS-WORD URL:Word Protocol and it should point to WORD (or whatever office program).

If you're more proficient then you can use the ftype command in cmd prompt to see the current settings for various extensions.

```
assoc .doc
```

should produce:

```
.doc=Word.Document.8
```

And...

```
ftype |findstr Word.Doc
```

should produce this list if you were using msoffice:

```
Word.Document.12="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\WINWORD.EXE" /n "%1" /o "%u"
Word.Document.8="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\WINWORD.EXE" /n "%1" /o "%u"
Word.DocumentMacroEnabled.12="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\WINWORD.EXE" /n "%1" /o "%u"
```

But there is a difference between filetypes and protocols and why you may be having problems... or it may even be the website that is messed up.